# worker node joins kubernetes cluster with flannel does not have cni0 created

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

I created a 3 nodes Kubernetes cluster `v1.10.4` with network plugin flannel `v0.10.0` on CentOS `7.5.1804` in VMware workstation v14. It ever worked well for a few days. But today when I brought up the machines, I see the two worker nodes do not have `cni0` virtual bridge created immediately after startup.

I tried delete node, re-join, reboot and all of these tries do not fix the issue. Only manually created the `cni0` can temporary work around that. But another reboot erased the settings again.

Even when `cni0` is missing, the `kubectl -n kube-system get pods` reports normal but actual inter-node communication through `10.244.0.0/12` does not work.

The cni package (`v0.6.0`) is installed on all nodes:

```
# rpm -qa | grep cni
kubernetes-cni-0.6.0-0.x86_64
```

Following are the commands to initialize the cluster:

```
# kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address 192.168.238.7 --kubernetes-version 1.10.4 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
# kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/v0.10.0/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
# after worker1 re-joined cluster:
# kubectl -n kube-system get pods -o wide
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP              NODE
etcd-master                      1/1       Running   0          2h        192.168.238.7   master
kube-apiserver-master            1/1       Running   0          2h        192.168.238.7   master
kube-controller-manager-master   1/1       Running   0          2h        192.168.238.7   master
kube-dns-86f4d74b45-cc2ph        3/3       Running   0          2h        10.244.0.8      master
kube-flannel-ds-fn6fx            1/1       Running   0          2h        192.168.238.7   master
kube-flannel-ds-h9qlf            1/1       Running   0          10m       192.168.238.8   worker1
kube-proxy-vjszc                 1/1       Running   0          2h        192.168.238.7   master
kube-proxy-z2bcp                 1/1       Running   0          10m       192.168.238.8   worker1
kube-scheduler-master            1/1       Running   0          2h        192.168.238.7   master
```

On worker1:

```
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:36:b0:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: ens34: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:36:b0:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:ef:0d:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:ef:0d:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:f0:ec:c8:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: flannel.1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:ec:81:b6:ef:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Routing table on worker1:

```
[root@worker1 ~]# ip ro
default via 192.168.64.2 dev ens34 
10.244.0.0/24 via 10.244.0.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
169.254.0.0/16 dev ens33 scope link metric 1002 
169.254.0.0/16 dev ens34 scope link metric 1003 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
192.168.64.0/24 dev ens34 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.64.135 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 
192.168.238.0/24 dev ens33 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.238.8
```

The docker version is: `v18.03`, the iptables rules is disabled for docker daemon.

```
# cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
    "iptables": false
}
```

Question is how would `cni0` got missing and never re-created by reboot or re-join kubernetes cluster? Are there any places that I should check?

One thing related to this is the kubernetes is deployed in VM so that I have to turned it on/off from time to time. But Kubernetes document does not have ever a procedure to handle such cluster shutdown operation except for tearing down the cluster at all. Is there any more elegant way to stop a cluster to avoid any potential damage to cluster integrity?

Comment: Best to post this on github as a k8s cni issue because it looks like it is a bug.

Comment: Good suggestion, will give it a try. Thanks